# Send AT command to a CDC reader and get response

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, serial-port, cdc

I have this CDC contactless reader that is connected with USB that appears as a virtual serial port. I'm able to find the port and send AT commands with the following code:

```
string strPort = GetPortName();

SerialPort srPort = new SerialPort(strPort, 9600);

srPort.Open();

if (srPort.IsOpen)
{
    //device info
    srPort.WriteLine(@"ATI\r" + (char)(13));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

    MessageBox.Show("Device: " + srPort.ReadExisting());

    //card UID
    srPort.WriteLine(@"AT+i\r" + (char)(13));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

    string strRes = srPort.ReadExisting();

    MessageBox.Show("UID: " + strRes);

    srPort.Close();
}
```

I am sending the commands according to the [device documentation](https://software.open-dev.ru/docs/online/usb_rfid/reference_cdc). First command goes OK, but the second, which is supposed to give me the card UID is always returning `ERROR`.

Am I sending the command string to the port in a right way? Because the second command has a `+` sign in between and I am thinking maybe it is the cause of the error?

I tried to contact their support, but no feedback. So I hope to get some help here.

Comment: First a Recommend using Asynchronous communications and not  Synchronous.  Also there is no need for Sleep instructions if you design the interface properly.  You should terminate line with "\n\r" not "\r\n". Data may com back in chunks due to timing that is built into Window operating so you need a loop and read until you get the end of line.

Comment: @jdweng Any tip on how to use Async communication in my case?

Comment: See msdn : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\r` means carriage return, it's not part of the literal command.

Comment: Also I think the srPort.WriteLine() command already append a '\r\n' depending on your operating system. Try using srPort.Write()

Comment: `(char)(13)` is not needed. It's `\r` which you write before.

Comment: Also documentation has error code details, you may post what error code you get on question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after testing reading and testing the commands from documentation, I realized that my reader was in Scan mode, which means it ignores all the commands sent to device. I turned the Scan mode off and was able to get the UID of the card.

I also replaced `WriteLine` with `Write' and used only ASCII byte array instead of a string command.